Facing issues with setting up Moveit2 with custom robot
I am encountering an issue with motion planning in the MoveIt2 framework. I have created a MoveIt configuration package for my custom robot using the MoveIt Setup Assistant, and I wrote a script similar to the hello_moveit example on the website.
Here's my code snippet:
#include <memory>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // Initialize ROS and create the Node
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto const node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(
    "hello_moveit",
    rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true)
  );

  // Create a ROS logger
  auto const logger = rclcpp::get_logger("hello_moveit");

  // Create the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface
  using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface;
  auto move_group_interface = MoveGroupInterface(node, "m2_arm");

  move_group_interface.setPlanningTime(15);
  move_group_interface.setNumPlanningAttempts(10);

  // Set a target Pose
  auto const target_pose = []{
    geometry_msgs::msg::Pose msg;
    msg.orientation.w = 1.0;
    msg.position.x = 0.2;
    msg.position.y = 0.2;
    msg.position.z = 0.2;
    return msg;
  }();
  move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(target_pose);

  // Create a plan to that target pose
  auto const [success, plan] = [&move_group_interface]{
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan msg;
    auto const ok = static_cast<bool>(move_group_interface.plan(msg));
    return std::make_pair(ok, msg);
  }();

  // Execute the plan
  if(success) {
    move_group_interface.execute(plan);
  } else {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(logger, "Planning failed!");
  }

  // Shutdown ROS
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

I execute the script with the following command:
ros2 run plan_using_moveit plan_using_moveit

Terminal Output
Here's the terminal output when I run the script:
[INFO] [1730117591.767709189] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 1.00116 seconds
[INFO] [1730117591.767769536] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'physics'...
[WARN] [1730117592.751783980] [moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[INFO] [1730117592.763678763] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group m2_arm.
[INFO] [1730117592.763775224] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[INFO] [1730117592.764384284] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[INFO] [1730117607.804645767] [move_group_interface]: Planning request aborted
[ERROR] [1730117607.804714445] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::plan() failed or timeout reached
[ERROR] [1730117607.804744300] [hello_moveit]: Planning failed!

In the terminal where I run my demo.launch.py script, I see the following messages:
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117592.764222994] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117592.764295673] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Executing...
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117592.771602180] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117592.772053840] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'm2_arm' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1730117607.778441015] [ompl]: ./src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/src/RRTConnect.cpp:252 - m2_arm/m2_arm: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1730117607.779802213] [ompl]: ./src/ompl/tools/multiplan/src/ParallelPlan.cpp:138 - ParallelPlan::solve(): Unable to find solution by any of the threads in 15.007609 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117607.804293642] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Unable to solve the planning problem
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1730117607.804330103] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Catastrophic failure

Troubleshooting Attempts
I've tried the following solutions without success:

Increased precision of the orientation coordinates.
Loaded kinematics parameters via a launch file.
Set the use_sim_time parameter to true.

None of these resolved the issue. The error message suggests that the planner (RRTConnect) is unable to sample valid states for the goal tree.
My MoveIt configuration and script files are available on GitHub: https://github.com/atharv180904/temp.
Help Needed
I'm not sure what else to try. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
